# How to insert data into database in liferay 6.2?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I created an entity userdetails with two fields name and password.Then through jsp, I passed parameters for both name and password. Then I tried to insert the same into the database.The code to insert data is as follows which is not working..

```
public void save(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws SystemException
{
    int id=(int) CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment();
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");
    System.out.println(name+ " " +password);
    userdetails ud=userdetailsLocalServiceUtil.createuserdetails(id);
    ud.setName(name);
    ud.setPassword(password);
    try {
        userdetailsLocalServiceUtil.adduserdetails(ud);
        //userdetailsPersistence.update(ud,false);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The code of jsp is as follows:-

```
<portlet:actionURL name="save" var="saveURL"></portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form method="post" action="<%= saveURL.toString() %>">
<aui:input name="name" type="text" />
<aui:input name="password" type="password" />
<aui:button type="submit" value="save" />
</aui:form>
```

Help please..

Comment: How is it not working? Do you see an error message? What is it?

Comment: No dear, no error message but the data in the table is not there..it's not working in terms of insertion into database.To be more specific.."userdetailsLocalServiceUtil.adduserdetails(ud);" is not working as it is intended to insert data...but no error message at all...Hope I have clarified my question..thanx in advance..

Comment: There is an error on line 13 of userdetailsLocalServiceUtil. I can see it using magic.

Comment: In the meantime, read this on how to ask a question: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question so that it has the relevant information

Comment: I checked line 13.No error was there.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Could you add in your user details impl class and meanwhile try debugging the impl class for any possible errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, follow proper naming convention for the entity className in `service.xml` (build service), like:

```
<entity name="UserDetails" local-service="true" remote-service="false" table="user_detail">
```

Create a new method (as below) in your `UserDetailsLocalServiceImpl.java` and build service again:

```
public UserDetails createUserDetails(String name, String password){

    UserDetails ud = UserDetailsUtil.create(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());
    ud.setName(name);
    ud.setPassword(password);
    UserDetails newUd = UserDetailsUtil.update(ud);

    return newUd;
}
```

That will copy its relevant entry in `UserDetailsLocalServiceUtil.java`. Now you use that method in you action method like as following:

```
public void save(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws SystemException {

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    System.out.println(name + " - " + password);

    try {
        UserDetails ud = UserDetailsLocalServiceUtil.createUserDetails(name, password);
        // Do whatever you want after creating new details
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```